# grrep only exactly matched line

Tags: grep

I have a file and it contains lines

```
users:x:22845:test1
test-users:x:22845:test2,test3
```

If I run `grep users: file`, it shows both lines becuase both have `users:`.

How can I get only `users:x:22845:`

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps specify that the line must start with "users". You can use the caret (^) special character to anchor the match at the beginning of the line:

```
egrep '^users:' file
```

This will not match the line beginning with "test-users".